# POST parameters sent by form but not present in php script

Tags: php, apache

I have a strange problem. I'm sending a very large form with hundreds of fields. Basically I have no doubt there is no errors with the form itself because in firefox's console I can see in my request that the POST array is present :

```
-----------------------------14624305211779581122436169227
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlocDocumentDocument[blocsTabulardocumentsTabularn0][n0][file]"

34495153-98c5-4200-8545-2bb71d279ecd
-----------------------------14624305211779581122436169227
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlocDocumentDocument[blocsTabulardocumentsTabularn0][n0][title]"

asdf
-----------------------------14624305211779581122436169227
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlocDocumentDocument[blocsTabulardocumentsTabularn0][n0][description]"


-----------------------------14624305211779581122436169227
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlocDocumentDocument[blocsTabulardocumentsTabularn0][n0][datetime]"

2014-09-19 00:00:00
-----------------------------14624305211779581122436169227
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BlocDocumentDocument[blocsTabulardocumentsTabularn0][n0][rank]"

1
```

But if in php I print_r($_POST['BlocDocumentDocument']['blocsTabulardocumentsTabularn0']) in the first line of php I get the following :

```
Array
(
    [n0] => Array
        (
            [file] => 34495153-98c5-4200-8545-2bb71d279ecd
        )

)
```

There are fields missing. And this problem seems to only occur if the form has a large amount of fields (I have the same form but with less fields (they're generated by javascript) and it works). I already tried to increase php's post_max_size and it didn't work.

Comment: You should post your code here. It's difficult to tell anything from this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It was php's max_input_vars setting. By default it's 1000 in 5.3.